# Execute user script node js (like CodingGame)

Tags: node.js

I'm currently building a CodingGame like platform for a school project and I wondered how I could handle user script validation.

The goal is to have multiple exercises to solve with an expected response.
For example, there's an error to correct in the exercise and when corrected it should output "hello".

I don't want users to actually do "console.log('hello')" in the IDE on the website if possible :)

The most difficult part is that i don't know how to do execute the actual script given (sent as text to the API).
I just want to start with NodeJS available for the user, no Php or C...

Save the script as localfile wouldn't be a good option I think, that's how we do it for now but I don't know how Coding test platforms actually do it.

The API is hosted on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux instances.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Programs are just strings. There is nothing wrong about saving it as files if that's what you already have. If you hit some sort of limitation then you can look for alternatives. One thing to consider is that you may want to sandbox or remove permissions from the execution so that uploaders don't `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` your EC2.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an elaborate business requirement and not simply a doubt, but some points that could help you to progress in your project further -

- A program is only a program when it is understood by some other program as instruction. Otherwise there's no difference in program.js and program.txt
- Validating and running a program are two different things
- Running a program on your own system vs allowing anyone to run the same program in your system are entirely different situations in terms of everything. (This is where the web & it's virtues come to play)
- There will always be some risk when letting others provide instructions to your systems, as no validation is 100% effective, even if you check for all destructive commands, there will always be more of them. But then again, you'll have to consider this while setting up a virtual machine for the sole purpose of public use. (Like, keeping in mind that this machine can be lost at any moment, so the architecture should be able to handle such losses, either by spinning up a new machine or having a set of replaceable machines for this.)
- Isolation & sandboxing of execution is the key in these kind of requirements. So you can have a look at tools like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), which could be a bit complex to understand initially, but if it suites your needs then simplicity is just one complexity away.